# Cross-domain interactions with a Java Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, cross-domain

I have a JavaScript web app on my server and I'm looking at the possibility of doing an AJAX connection with an existing Java servlet on a different server. I'm collaborating with the servlet developer, but he is currently dealing with other projects, and I'm trying to see how much I can get done without him needing to do anything. He's not too familiar with JS and I don't have any Java experience... but we've got a lot of good intentions!

His servlet has an HTML form interface sending a POST request. As a first step I downloaded his form, uploaded it to my server and changed the form's `action` to an absolute URL, from

```
<form action="/path/to/Servlet" [...] >
```

to

```
<form action="http://remoteserver.com/path/to/Servlet" [...] >
```

When I test the form on his server, it works fine, but when I test with the same exact input on the form on my server, the server returns a 500 error with a Java exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    Filechange_b2.doPost(Filechange_b2.java:322)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I realize that this is a bit of a black box problem, but based on these clues, is there anything I can do from my end? It's my understanding that a form request wouldn't trigger any CORS-related security issues; my hunch based on the code here is that there is something in his code that is relying on the assumption that input is coming from a local page.

Any ideas to go on here? Thanks very much for your help.

**EDIT:** Okay, looks like the JSP/Java interaction is more complicated than I originally thought and involves passing a session ID back and forth. That at least gives me something more to go on. Yay learning!

Comment: Is Filechange_b2 trying to read a cookie or header?

Comment: Good question. It looks like there is a cookie with a name JSESSIONID, and in trying to track it down I see that the form page is a .jsp file (another language I don't have any experience in, but I'm assuming it's akin to php which I am familiar with). Do servlets like this one often set and check session IDs as a security measure?

Comment: servlets generally can receive request from different domains. do you have access to Filechange_b2 at line 322?

Comment: I don't... I'm guessing I'm going to need to wait for the servlet developer to take a look at it and get back to me. (I had also thought to try to send a request to the file which sets the cookie and read it programmatically, but it looks like the cookie is set to be httpOnly.)